# How to write user login error in login page

Tags: go

I'm new one for Golang programming. In Golang how to display the username error.
This is my code:

```
func LoginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    if req.Method == http.MethodPost{

        un := req.FormValue("username")
        p  := req.FormValue("password")

        u, ok := dbUsers[un]
        if !ok{
            var body, _ = helpers.LoadFile("sss/login.html")
            fmt.Fprintf(response, body)
            //fmt.Fprintln(w, "incorrect user name")
            //return
        }
        if u.Password != p{
            fmt.Fprintln(w, "incorrect password")
            return
        }

        http.Redirect(w, req, "/index.html", http.StatusSeeOther)
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In go You have different ways for error handling

```
func SomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error) {
if req.Method == http.MethodPost{

    un := req.FormValue("username")
    p  := req.FormValue("password")

    u, ok := dbUsers[un]
    if !ok{
        var body, _ = helpers.LoadFile("sss/login.html")
        return 400, errors.New("can't load sss/login")

    }
    if u.Password != p{
        return 400, errors.New("wrong password")
    }

    http.Redirect(w, req, "/index.html", http.StatusSeeOther)
    return 302, nil
}
```

or

```
func SomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    un := req.FormValue("username")
    p  := req.FormValue("password")

    u, ok := dbUsers[un]
    if !ok{
        var body, _ = helpers.LoadFile("sss/login.html")
        http.Error(w, "can't load sss/login", 400)
        return

    }
    if u.Password != p{
        http.Error(w, "wrong password", 400)
        return

    }

    http.Redirect(w, req, "/index.html", http.StatusSeeOther)
    return
}
```

For more information You can read here very helpful blogpost about middlewares: 
https://www.nicolasmerouze.com/middlewares-golang-best-practices-examples/

Post with simple example:
https://blog.questionable.services/article/http-handler-error-handling-revisited/

Http package docs: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

Comment: http.Error can't set the response status if you write to the ResponseWriter beforehand (and the Fprintln calls seem redundant anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something a little bit more elegant.
Pass a context object to the template and render the error there.

```
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    context := make(map[string]string]
    context["Error"] = "Username error"
    t := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("./templates/index.html"))
    t.Execute(w, context)
}
```

Then, on the template render it like this

```
{{.Error}}}
```

If no error occurred, the field will be empty.
Cheers.